# On clicking the form divert to another PHP page with the results of the check box

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html-table, comparison

I have a set of check boxes on one page and submit button with value="compare" is out of the form. I have written a jQuery for the button compare outside of the form. I am comparing a set of tables side by side. My code works fine in the same Page. I don't know how to display the result in another page. Anyone please help me.

```
<?php
require('db.php');


?>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Comparision</title>
</head>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#compare_id").click( function(){
$("input:checkbox:not(:checked)").each(function() {
    var column = "table ." + $(this).attr("name");
    $(column).hide();
});
    });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#compare_id").click( function(){
$("input:checkbox:(:checked)").each(function(){
    var column = "table ." + $(this).attr("name");
    $(column).toggle();
});
    });
});


</script>
</head>
<body>
<input name="compare" id="compare_id" type="button" value="Compare"  />

<form  action="test.php"  method="post" name="printers_comparision">
  <p>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="p1" value="Printer1" id="CheckboxGroup1_0" />
      Printer1</label>

    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="p2" value="Printer2" id="CheckboxGroup1_1" />
      Printer2</label>

    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="p3" value="Printer3" id="CheckboxGroup1_2" />
      Printer3</label>

    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="p4" value="Pritner4" id="CheckboxGroup1_3" />
      Printer4</label>

    <label>


</form>
<table width="1023" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td width="193"></td>
    <td class="p1" width="113"><img src="images/im.png"/></td>
    <td class="p2" width="67"><img  src="images/im.png"/></td>
    <td class="p3" width="67"><img  src="images/im.png"/></td>
    <td class="p4" width="67"><img  src="images/im.png"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Title</td>
    <td class="p1" >Printer1</td>
    <td class="p2" >Printer2</td>
    <td class="p3" >Printer3</td>
    <td class="p4" >Printer4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Manufacturer</td>
    <td class="p1" ><?php $query=mysql_query('select Manufacturer from printers where printers_id="1";');
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)) echo $row['Manufacturer'] ?></td>
    <td class="p2" ><?php $query=mysql_query('select Manufacturer from printers where printers_id="2";');
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)) echo $row['Manufacturer'] ?></td>
    <td class="p3" ><?php $query=mysql_query('select Manufacturer from printers where printers_id="3";');
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)) echo $row['Manufacturer'] ?></td>
    <td class="p4" ><?php $query=mysql_query('select Manufacturer from printers where printers_id="4";');
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)) echo $row['Manufacturer'] ?></td>
</tr>
</body>
</table>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try out using `SESSION` variables or setting `COOKIE` in case you need to show data across pages

Comment: This one is extremely simple. Anyways, everyone starts from scratch so I will show you. To set a value using session, use this: `$_SESSION['some_index'] = 'some value';` To retrieve this value, you should use `$some_var = $_SESSION['some_index']`; Every PHP file should have `session_start()` as the first line and no output should have been sent to the browser prior to setting a session. Ask more if you face difficulty in understanding

Comment: For the sake of simplicity, you can have a look into these 2 basic tutorials 1) http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp 2) http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp

Comment: I suggest you to have a look into the possibility of sending the data (which you have already sent) and recieving the information in a PHP script. This might solve the problem.

Comment: does it really work for the above case? Sorry I didn't get it

Comment: Oops... I misread your comment. Please go through the link provided. you might solve your problem that ways.

Comment: do you mean w3schools? link

Comment: No it didn't help me. Please anybody help me. Thanks

Comment: hi Ankur Kumar if you know solution. Please tell me

Comment: Hi. SO is a site meant for sharing knowledge and take engineering to newer heights. This is possible only if people help one another by SHOWING the correct path. I suggest you do more research on your problem and come up with the latest update as to where you have reached while solving your problem. I am sorry if I sounded offensive.. I did not mean hurting someone :)

Comment: I know that i have to use session to store the data and call it another screen. I am here to get a solution and not a suggestion. You probably spoiled my question and i didn't receive any more answers for this. If you don't know the solution never give any suggestion. Thanks

Comment: Nobody stoppped anybody from answering. Anyone who answers a question would read it first. If you still think that I have spoilt your question, all the best, find good answers.